# Не верные (разные) данные с OpenWeatherMap

Tags: android, weather, openweathermap

Приложение с прогнозом погоды. Данные беру с OpenWeatherMap. Почему при написании на разных языках выводятся разные данные??[image: 1 - написано на укр языке, 2 - на русском]

Вот код запроса (переменная city - это input с EditText)

```html
  public static JSONObject getJSON(Context context, String city){
        try {
            URL url = new URL(String.format(OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API, city));
            HttpURLConnection connection =
                    (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            connection.addRequestProperty("x-api-key",
                    context.getString(R.string.open_weather_map_id));

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            StringBuffer json = new StringBuffer(1024);
            String tmp="";
            while((tmp=reader.readLine())!=null)
                json.append(tmp).append("\n");
            reader.close();

            JSONObject data = new JSONObject(json.toString());

            
            if(data.getInt("cod") != 200){
                return null;
            }

            return data;
        }catch(Exception e){
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать разработчикам/администраторам соответствующего сайта.

Comment: А какой запрос вы отправляете на сервер?

Comment: плюсую, это связано с авторами ресурса. Код всет-таки надо было привести. Так никакого другого ответа вы не получите)

Answer (score 2):

https://openweathermap.org/current#multi - язык должен быть указан параметром `lang=ua`. А после запятой в параметре `q=Nikolayev,ru` - это страна.
Но даже на Украине он не один: [ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Николаев](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%B2_(%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)#%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B) - надо как-то ещё уточнять запрос.